# Is there a preferred tequila age for Strawberries Por Mi Amante?

Tags: alcohol, strawberries

I'd like to soak strawberries in tequila for a Por Mi Amante.  I'm not concerned about the brand, but I'm curious if there is a flavor difference as a result of soaking in *blanco* vs *reposado* vs *añejo*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Cocktailians recommend Reposado](http://www.cocktailians.com/2011/08/tequila-y-paloma-por-mi-amante.html): "use the 100% agave stuff, and definitely go for the reposado -- you want something with a little age and character". Paul Clarke quotes [cocktail luminary Charles H Baker](http://partycocktails.com/misc/cocktail_experts.html#baker)'s [recipe from 1939](http://www.cocktailchronicles.com/2007/06/21/tequila-por-mi-amante/), which is non-specific, but Paul also uses Reposado.

Blanco is likely to be a little too light and easily dominated by the strawberries, a good Añejo is probably overkill, so a decent Reposado fits the bill.

Comment: @PeterTaylor thank you for noticing, I edited the post. As we are a collaboratively edited site, feel free to edit it yourself next time. Even if you don't have the rep yet, a mod or a 10k user will see that there is an edit pending and approve it.

Comment: @rumtscho, the SE software won't let low-rep users make one-character edits.